# Code secure protection

Tags: r, unix, trace, code-security

I wrote an R script on an institutional computer. I saved it on an external device (USB PenDrive) and tested it on a computer not of my institution. When I run it to test it using R from Terminal and from GUI I never saved it on the host computer.

This because it has to remain secret until it will be published. I simply would like to know if R or Unix itself saved it elsewhere while running although I load it directly giving the path of Volumes and so on.

In other words the question is does running an R script off a USB leave any trace of it on the host computer.

P.S.: I checked the R history to look for it but it seems not to be saved.

Comment: maybe make the question a bit more clear, i think you are asking "does running an r script off a usb leave any trace of it on the computer"?

Comment: Exactly. I will edit it soon.Thank you so much.